# The Underlying Connection Was Closed. Could not establish trust relationship with remote server

Tags: c#, ssl

I'm trying to connect to a web service through HTTPS.
I had success configuring a self-signed certificate by referring to this link [Setting up IIS with HTTPS Binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/823177)

Now I added some code to the handheld device to call the web service. I had referred to several websites and saw the same code.

```
public class MyPolicy : ICertificatePolicy
        {
            public bool CheckValidationResult(
                  ServicePoint srvPoint
                , X509Certificate certificate
                , WebRequest request
                , int certificateProblem)
            {

                //Return True to force the certificate to be accepted.
                return true;
            } // end CheckValidationResult
        } // class MyPolicy
```

I also added this line before calling the web service

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();
```

But I am still getting the error: `Could not establish trust relationship with remote server.`

Any clues on what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

The handheld code probably doesn't trust your self-signed certificate.  You have to override the default certificate handling to allow it.  When calling from a browser, this triggers a warning dialog which allows you to trust the self-signed certificate in a specific case.

Comment: but the code already indicate not matter what certificate, it will always return true. Or do I need to install any cert at client side too?

Comment: Were they all self-signed certificates?  All of those are not trusted by default.

Comment: Yes. Those are self-signed certificates. So u mean they not trusted from client side or server side?

Comment: Self-signed certificates are NOT trusted by any clients by default.  If they were, you could create a self-signed certificate for Google.com and have all sorts of fun.